# is there a way to focus on a specific tab in chrome (via plugin)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to be able to focus on a specific tab.

After `chrome.tabs.query` I get the `id` but how do I set focus on that tab? I don't see this option in the documentation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [chrome.tabs.update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update).

```
var updateProperties = { 'active': true };
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, updateProperties, (tab) => { });
```

Comment: And for V3 ? :)

Comment: V3 is a change to the format of the manifest file format. The general API version is not changing.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-highlight

```
chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.highlight({'tabs': tab.index}, function() {});
});
```

Comment: This is more correct because this method seems to be designed for tab (or tab group) focusing.

Comment: @avalanche1 that's not true. Multiple tabs can be highlighted at once by holding `shift`. When you "highlight" a tab, "activating" is just a side effect. You can only have one active tab per window but multiple highlighted tabs.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that highlighting is a feature meant for grouping tabs for bulk operations whereas the property of being active is the tab which is currently in view in the browser window and accepting keyboard input?