# periodically reload tab and bring to front

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a requirement where a few users are required to keep a watch over a dashboard browser page.

My first thought was use some javascript magic that reloads the page, switches to it if it is not active and being the browser window to front. I quickly realized how difficult this (accept for reload) is and that browsers do everything possible to prevent it, with good reason.

On the other hand, I have err, seen some "websites" which show a pop-up telling me that my browser is affected and I need to call the given 800 number. These pop-ups are pretty much impossible to kill. I could use that if I knew how.

I have also considered utilities like [ergociser](http://download.cnet.com/The-Ergociser/3000-2129_4-10398225.html) which sit in the taskbar and open a browser window periodically. This could work but it opens a *new* pop-up window every time, while I am keen to reload it in the same window.

The closest I have come so far is to use `alert` which does not bring the window to front but it does flash the taskbar.

I am thinking of a chrome extension or firefox add-on that brings named pop-up tab. But I am open to any other ideas. It can be a browser specific solution, and it is ok to require white-listing in pop-up blockers

What is a best way to do this?

**UPDATE**
There are two close votes for "Too Broad". It is true that I am looking for the right technology to use for this problem, so I cannot refine it with technology-specific details. But short of that, appreciate if someone can give suggestion for narrowing down the problem statement.

Comment: [notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/Notification) sounds to be good but is limited compatibility. [test](http://mdn.github.io/emogotchi/)

Comment: @Searching notification would only remind a user to switch to the tab, it won't bring it to foreground, right?

Comment: show us what you tried so far with a chrome extension. it is possible with extensions to select and focus tabs.

Comment: true. but it would be a combination of multiple apis. If you take the browser extension path, i believe you can get the `tabId` and then perform these in combination... (tabId)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/25226679/1339516]

Comment: @ZigMandel I have to confess I haven't tried anything yet. I am trying to find out if it is viable approach. It seems it is, so my next question(s) will be more specific.

Comment: Notification compatibility is fairly good with the exception of IE see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/Notification#Browser_compatibility another option if you are interested in going the add-on route is a browser sidebar (Something like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/all-in-one-sidebar/ You might be able to use that one as is

Comment: @MarcRohloff browser compatibility is not an issue -- this is intended for a small set of users who can use whichever browser works best for the purpose. But as far as I can tell Notification API only displays notification. I don't see any way to bring the browser tab to foreground when user clicks om the Notification. Am I missing something?

Comment: ive done this from a chrome extension. chrome tabs/windows apis have ability to focus and select tabs.

Comment: It might be a built in response and not something you have to configure. I know that if I click on a notification generated by Slack (I'm using Firefox) then it takes me to the correct tab.