# Make site/tab think it's in focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension which updates a tab with a URLs in LinkedIn (every some times it changes the URL). The problem is that URLs in LinkedIn don't fully load until the user is focused on that site/tab, and I need the page to load when the user is using other tabs as well.

So is there any way I can use JavaScript (either using Chrome's background script, or a content script which will execute in the required tab) to make LinkedIn think the page is in focus, so that it loads fully?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225964/is-there-a-way-to-focus-on-a-specific-tab-in-chrome-via-plugin

Comment: @ChrisSatchell This doesn't simulate focus, it actually focuses on the tab. I'm asking about letting the tab/site *think* it's focused, without actually being in focus (i.e. the user will be able to stay on another tab).

Comment: There's no universal solution and you'll have to hack the site script by monkey-patching the relevant code, which is generally not possible in Chrome extension alone (but it's possible in Firefox). As a workaround, you can probably open the site in a very small separate window positioned somewhere in a corner of the screen, wait for it to load, then move that tab into the main window with chrome.tabs.move. AFAIK being the only tab in a window makes it focused as far as the page visibility API is concerned. Maybe you can even open that window in background and still get it to work.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, at least I won't scour the web for something that isn't possible. I'll try your suggestion with the window.